# Netty 3.x one client connection and multiple requests

Tags: java, netty

I am developing an application that is using netty as client to connect to a server. The requirements are such that only and only one connection is allowed to the server. However that connection should be able to server multiple concurrent requests as many as possible. One of my solution to the problem is to use the BlockingQueue but the throughput was not the best. The reason why I used to the blockingqueue is that it helps me to match requests to response easily since the architecture is request/response.

Now I would like to know how best to rewrite that client side to send concurrent requests and get the appropriate response without using the blockingqueue.

Please assist me with any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply include a unique message identity in the request which is also included in the reply. Then, in the client, use a `ConcurrentMap` to temporarily store the context information for each request and use it for matching replies.

I would also hide this mechanism behind a suitable API:

```
void sendReceive(Request request, Handler<Response> responseHandler);
```